# error using cdfextract in R (clim.pact package)

Tags: r, csv, netcdf

I am fairly new at using R and I am currently trying to use it to extract data for a specific region of a netCDF file and convert it to a csv.  Ultimately I would like to have a timeseries for each variable over my area of interest.

I've downloaded the packages `ncdf` and `clim.pact` for R, and as my netCDF file is quite large (daily data for 25 years) I think I should be able to extract a the data for my region of interest using cdfextract, and then I will convert that smaller file to a csv.  Howver, I keep getting the same error when I try to run it.  This is the script I've been using and the error that comes up:

```
cdfextract("file.nc","tas", x.rng=c(-93, -85), y.rng=c(16, 23),t.rng=c(1, 9125))
```

> [1] "time.origin= 01 Jan 0850"
>   Error in system("rm -f cdfcont.txt", intern = TRUE) : 'rm' not found

Where my file is `file.nc` and the variable of interest is `tas`.  I think it may have something to do with the time format, but when I check the time units of the file it says it is in "days since 01 Jan 0850" so I think the units are right.

Anyways any comments on this issue would be very welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to use R, you can use `ncks` from the NCO package: http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncks-netCDF-Kitchen-Sink

`ncks` is a wonderful command-line tool for extracting data from netCDF files.  In general, you can extract a variable over certain lat/lon bands and then output that data into a .csv file using something like:

```
ncks -v tas -d lat,16.,23. -d lon,-93.,-85. -s '%f\n' file.nc > output.csv
```

I couldn't tell if you wanted an area-average of `tas` first and then a time series of that area-averaged quantity in the .csv file.  If so, you'll need to use `ncwa` to perform the area averaging first: http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#Averaging

Comment: Thanks! That's a great suggestion, I don't have to use R but since I have used R a couple times before I thought I would start there.  But that package sounds like that could do the trick, I will give it a try!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the ncks package, it definitely does the trick! I ended up downloading NCO for windows from from http://nco.sourceforge.net/src/nco-4.2.0.windows.mvs.exe.

Comment: Great!  NCO is a good place to start anytime you are working with netCDF data.  Keep it in the back of your mind when you deal with that kind of data in the future.